# Excel Dynamic Ranges changing (with no logic)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

A confusing one.  I'm using a dynamic range

```
=OFFSET('EA OPs'!A4,0,0,COUNTA('EA OPs'!$A:$A)-1,96)
```

I've assigned it to `rOps` in the NAME MANAGER.  I've then tried to change a Pivot Table source to `rOps`.  Click in to a random cell.  Click back in the NAME MANAGER and it has changed to:

```
=OFFSET('EA OPs'!G3,0,0,COUNTA('EA OPs'!$A:$A)-1,96)
```

then

```
=OFFSET('EA OPs'!G24,0,0,COUNTA('EA OPs'!$A:$A)-1,96)
```

seemingly at random.  Althought it does seem to keep near to the cell I've clicked on?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor the `A4` with dollar signs and make it an absolute reference. Otherwise it's relative to whatever cell is active:

```
=OFFSET('EA OPs'!$A$4,0,0,COUNTA('EA OPs'!$A:$A)-1,96)
```

Named ranges always behave this way, which can be useful. For example with A2 active, you can create a range named "CellAbove" and set it to "=A1". You can then use it in a formula in any cell, e.g., `=CellAbove/2' and the result will be the value of the cell one row up, divided by 2.

Comment: I've never really used them before, so it confused the hell out of me.  Thank you, was about to throw the laptop out the window! LOL